Nprobe command line configurations
As per the nprobe documentation below the parameters and their description:
-w: size of the hash that stores the flows
-M: maximum number of active flows
Are both these parameters corelated or depends on each other like for example value of -w should always be greater or equal to -M.
If yes, please explain how the active flows is tracked? are the active flows stored in hash?
what is the optimum value that needs to be set for both of these parameters.
